# Size limits with MSVC Community {2017}

Tags: exception, visual-c++

ALL,

Is there any kind of limitation when developing with MSVC Community {2017}? Either by the source code or an object file/binary?

My program is C++ based and all of a sudden I started getting "CreateWindowEx failed (error code 0)" error in the log and getting an exception because hWnd is NULL.

Nothing changed in that area, and it just starts occuring.

I don't even know where to begin...

TIA!!

P.S.: I'm using both Win 8.1 (regular) and 10 (in a VM) if it matters...

EDIT:

I ran the program nder AppVerifier.

Log is below:

```
<avrf:logfile>
<avrf:logSession TimeStarted="2022-06-27 : 08:49:31" PID="7020" Version="2">
<avrf:logEntry Time="2022-06-27 : 08:49:33" LayerName="LuaPriv" StopCode="0x33FF" Severity="Information">
<avrf:message>Information: LUAPriv version.</avrf:message>
<avrf:formatmessage>LUAPriv version: 1.0</avrf:formatmessage>
<avrf:parameter1>1 - Version major</avrf:parameter1>
<avrf:parameter2>0 - Version minor</avrf:parameter2>
<avrf:parameter3>0 - n/a</avrf:parameter3>
<avrf:parameter4>0 - n/a</avrf:parameter4>
</avrf:logEntry>
<avrf:logEntry Time="2022-06-27 : 08:49:33" LayerName="LuaPriv" StopCode="0x333A" Severity="Information">
<avrf:message>Information: Application file name.</avrf:message>
<avrf:formatmessage>
C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app\dbhandler\vc_mswuddll\docview.exe
</avrf:formatmessage>
<avrf:parameter1>92ee60 - File Name</avrf:parameter1>
<avrf:parameter2>0 - n/a</avrf:parameter2>
<avrf:parameter3>0 - n/a</avrf:parameter3>
<avrf:parameter4>0 - n/a</avrf:parameter4>
</avrf:logEntry>
<avrf:logEntry Time="2022-06-27 : 08:49:33" LayerName="LuaPriv" StopCode="0x3304" Severity="Warning">
<avrf:message>Initialization failed.</avrf:message>
<avrf:formatmessage>
Profile: The USERPROFILE environment variable could not be found
</avrf:formatmessage>
<avrf:parameter1>55255638 - N/A</avrf:parameter1>
<avrf:parameter2>521 - N/A</avrf:parameter2>
<avrf:parameter3>0 - N/A</avrf:parameter3>
<avrf:parameter4>0 - N/A</avrf:parameter4>
<avrf:stackTrace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+55264c03 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+55264c50 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+55264342 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+552669ae ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+55267f0d ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+5526685c ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
verifier!VerifierGetPropertyValueByName+5b84 ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vrfcore!VerifierTlsSetValue+48a ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfbasics!+5397aa24 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+10e ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+88 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
ntdll!RtlIsCriticalSectionLockedByThread+2a5 ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
ntdll!RtlIsCriticalSectionLockedByThread+1ed ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlRemoveVectoredContinueHandler+2fc ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!LdrGetDllPath+9300 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeHandleTable+45 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+10 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
</avrf:stackTrace>
</avrf:logEntry>
<avrf:logEntry Time="2022-06-27 : 08:49:34" LayerName="LuaPriv" StopCode="0x3319" Severity="Warning">
<avrf:message>Unable to display a security descriptor.</avrf:message>
<avrf:formatmessage>
Could not convert Key security descriptor '\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OLE' to text due to error 0x8
</avrf:formatmessage>
<avrf:parameter1>9a89fa0 - Object Name</avrf:parameter1>
<avrf:parameter2>55253ad0 - Object Type</avrf:parameter2>
<avrf:parameter3>9a8bf60 - Security Descriptor</avrf:parameter3>
<avrf:parameter4>8 - Win32 Error</avrf:parameter4>
<avrf:stackTrace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+55258487 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+55259084 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+5525fdb9 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>combase!ObjectStublessClient18+1999 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>combase!ObjectStublessClient18+12ae ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
</avrf:stackTrace>
</avrf:logEntry>
<avrf:logEntry Time="2022-06-27 : 08:49:34" LayerName="LuaPriv" StopCode="0x332E" Severity="Warning">
<avrf:message>
The application called an API that failed unexpectedly, possibly due to bad parameters.
</avrf:message>
<avrf:formatmessage>
RegOpenKeyExW: Key (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\OLE\Tracing) is denied 'READ_CONTROL KEY_QUERY_VALUE KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS KEY_NOTIFY' access with error 0x2.
</avrf:formatmessage>
<avrf:parameter1>2 - Error returned</avrf:parameter1>
<avrf:parameter2>20019 - Access Requested (if applicable)</avrf:parameter2>
<avrf:parameter3>20019 - Access Requested (for compatibility)</avrf:parameter3>
<avrf:parameter4>0 - n/a</avrf:parameter4>
<avrf:stackTrace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+5526408e ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+5525fd30 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>combase!ObjectStublessClient18+ddc ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>combase!ObjectStublessClient18+137a ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>combase!CoTaskMemAlloc+115 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
verifier!VerifierGetPropertyValueByName+5b84 ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vrfcore!VerifierTlsSetValue+48a ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfbasics!+5397aa24 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+10e ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+88 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
ntdll!RtlIsCriticalSectionLockedByThread+2a5 ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
ntdll!RtlIsCriticalSectionLockedByThread+1ed ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeHandleTable+e8d ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeHandleTable+45 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+10 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
</avrf:stackTrace>
</avrf:logEntry>
<avrf:logEntry Time="2022-06-27 : 08:49:34" LayerName="LuaPriv" StopCode="0x332E" Severity="Warning">
<avrf:message>
The application called an API that failed unexpectedly, possibly due to bad parameters.
</avrf:message>
<avrf:formatmessage>
OpenEventA: Event (HookSwitchHookEnabledEvent) is denied 'SYNCHRONIZE' access with error 0x2.
</avrf:formatmessage>
<avrf:parameter1>2 - Error returned</avrf:parameter1>
<avrf:parameter2>100000 - Access Requested (if applicable)</avrf:parameter2>
<avrf:parameter3>100000 - Access Requested (for compatibility)</avrf:parameter3>
<avrf:parameter4>0 - n/a</avrf:parameter4>
<avrf:stackTrace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+5526408e ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+5525d8a7 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>combase!ObjectStublessClient18+1042 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>combase!ObjectStublessClient18+142b ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>combase!CoTaskMemAlloc+115 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
verifier!VerifierGetPropertyValueByName+5b84 ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vrfcore!VerifierTlsSetValue+48a ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfbasics!+5397aa24 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+10e ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+88 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
ntdll!RtlIsCriticalSectionLockedByThread+2a5 ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
ntdll!RtlIsCriticalSectionLockedByThread+1ed ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeHandleTable+e8d ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeHandleTable+45 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+10 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
</avrf:stackTrace>
</avrf:logEntry>
<avrf:logEntry Time="2022-06-27 : 08:49:34" LayerName="LuaPriv" StopCode="0x332E" Severity="Warning">
<avrf:message>
The application called an API that failed unexpectedly, possibly due to bad parameters.
</avrf:message>
<avrf:formatmessage>
RegOpenKeyExW: Key (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\OLE\Tracing) is denied 'READ_CONTROL KEY_QUERY_VALUE KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS KEY_NOTIFY' access with error 0x2.
</avrf:formatmessage>
<avrf:parameter1>2 - Error returned</avrf:parameter1>
<avrf:parameter2>20019 - Access Requested (if applicable)</avrf:parameter2>
<avrf:parameter3>20019 - Access Requested (for compatibility)</avrf:parameter3>
<avrf:parameter4>0 - n/a</avrf:parameter4>
<avrf:stackTrace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+5526408e ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfluapriv!+5525fd30 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ole32!OleReleaseEnumVerbCache+e75 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ole32!OleReleaseEnumVerbCache+81f ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ole32!+7537468a ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
verifier!VerifierGetPropertyValueByName+5b84 ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vrfcore!VerifierTlsSetValue+48a ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>vfbasics!+5397aa24 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+10e ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSection+88 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
ntdll!RtlIsCriticalSectionLockedByThread+2a5 ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>
ntdll!RtlIsCriticalSectionLockedByThread+1ed ( @ 0)
</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlGetVersion+7c0 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeHandleTable+e8d ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!RtlInitializeHandleTable+45 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
<avrf:trace>ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+10 ( @ 0)</avrf:trace>
</avrf:stackTrace>
</avrf:logEntry>
</avrf:logSession>
</avrf:logfile>
```

Comment: No limitations imposed by the compiler. Windows does have limits on resources available, so if you're leaking handles you could have a problem. [Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/application-verifier) can help you find those sorts of issues. Without seeing the code it's hard to know what might be going wrong. If you have an error it is important that `GetLastError` is called immediately to capture the error.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, does this `Application Verifier` exist for version 2017? I did install the full package and a lot of different SDKs...

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I found it and run my program with it. I attached the log. Can you spot any issues?